# How to set a font family to "erewhon" when using Latex in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, latex, tex

I am using the latex format for the axis label and axis tick label for some of my plots. My problem is that the latex font differs from the non-latex font which is 'erewhon'. So I want to try to use 'erewhon' in the latex format.

I tried multiple approaches like the following code:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,5))

rcParams = [{'text.usetex': True,
         'svg.fonttype': 'none',
         'text.latex.preamble': r'\usepackage{erewhon}',
         'font.size': 20,
         'font.family': 'erewhon',
         'mathtext.fontset': 'custom',
         'mathtext.rm': 'erewhon',
         'mathtext.it': 'erewhon',
         'mathtext.bf': 'erewhon'}]


xlabel='Oxygen mass flow (sccm)'
ylabel1=r'$\mathrm{\rho \; (\mu \Omega \cdot cm)}$'

ax1.semilogy(xfit, ( np.exp(m*xfit+b) ) , 'k-', lw=2)
ax1.set_yscale('log')

ax1.set_xlabel(xlabel, fontsize=20)
ax1.set_ylabel(ylabel1, fontsize=20)
```

This code provides the xlabel font to be 'erewhon' but the ylabel still uses any font (I even don't know which one), although, I use \mathrm{}. Is there any solution for this problem?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suppose `erewhon` font does not have math mode symbols? If you compile a latex document with that font, would math mode (e.g. `$5 \times 10^{-3}$`) show up in the desired font?

Comment: Try loading `newtxmath` with option `erewhon` in addition to the `erehon` package, c.f. https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/erewhon/

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, it seems to appear in the 'erewhon' font, or at least in a serif font.

Comment: @RalfStubner Unfortunately, it did not solve my problem and the labels still appear in latex sans serif font :(

Comment: Note that in the code you show here, you do not apply the rc parameters to the `rcParams` of matplotlib, so they are simply ignored.

Comment: I just tested, @RalfStubner 's suggestion [works nicely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78OUt.png). So probably you made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Maybe I am that newbie - I now use that code snippet: rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['erewhon']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r'\usepackage[erewhon,vvarbb,bigdelims]{newtxmath}'] but it still appear in latex sans serif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the [super helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359358/how-to-set-a-font-family-when-using-latex-in-matplotlib?noredirect=1#comment101207970_57359358) by Ralf Stubner here, this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

preamble = [r"\usepackage[proportional,scaled=1.064]{erewhon}", 
            r"\usepackage[erewhon,vvarbb,bigdelims]{newtxmath}", 
            r"\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}",
            r"\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\textosf{#1}}"]

rcParams = {'text.usetex': True,
         'svg.fonttype': 'none',
         'text.latex.preamble': preamble,
         'font.size': 20,
         'font.family': 'erewhon'}
plt.rcParams.update(rcParams)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,5))



xlabel='Oxygen mass flow (sccm)'
ylabel1=r'$\mathrm{\rho \; (\mu \Omega \cdot cm)}$'

#ax1.semilogy(xfit, ( np.exp(m*xfit+b) ) , 'k-', lw=2)
ax1.set_yscale('log')

ax1.set_xlabel(xlabel, fontsize=20)
ax1.set_ylabel(ylabel1, fontsize=20)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Yes!! That's exactly what I needed, thank you that much! I was struggling with this problems since a week till now!! I guess I now only have to use the siunitx package to show the \Omega. Thank you!! :)

Comment: @IzzyQ2q `siuntx` is a good idea. As a minimal fix use `ylabel1=r'$\rho \; (\mu \Omega \cdot \mathrm{cm})$'`.